# Electron (main) notification API 'on.click' event not always working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a problem with the [Electron notification API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/notification). I always got the notification but very often the click event on notification is not executed. Sometimes click event will be executed only the first 2 times, sometimes only the tenth time, and sometimes not at all.

The video file with problem: [VIDEO](https://puu.sh/GGrQz/36b036eb4d.mp4)

There is my code:

```
function showNotification () {
    const notificationOptions = {
        title: 'SysInfoGrabber',
        body: 'Raport PDF został utworzony na pulpicie w folderze "Raporty"',
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'files/icon.png')
    }
    const reportNotification = new Notification(notificationOptions);
    
    reportNotification.on('show', () => { 
        console.log('Notification is shown'); 
    });
    reportNotification.on('click', () => {
        console.log("Notification clicked");
    });
    reportNotification.show();  
}


mainFunction(){

    [...CODE...]

    // Show notify
    showNotification();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're running into is probably caused by the fact that the constant `reportNotification` is declared *locally* inside the `showNotification()` function, and will get garbage-collected some time after the function is exited, and the event handlers attached to it won't be usable any longer.

Try to declare `reportNotification` *globally* as a variable (using `let`) outside any other function(s).

```
let reportNotification;

function showNotification () {
    const notificationOptions = {
        title: 'SysInfoGrabber',
        body: 'Raport PDF został utworzony na pulpicie w folderze "Raporty"',
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'files/icon.png')
    }
    reportNotification = new Notification(notificationOptions);
    
    reportNotification.on('show', () => { 
        console.log('Notification is shown'); 
    });
    reportNotification.on('click', () => {
        console.log("Notification clicked");
    });
    reportNotification.show();  
}


mainFunction(){

    [...CODE...]

    // Show notify
    showNotification();
}
```

Comment: I don't think an object with existing attached listeners ('show', 'click') is getting GC'd

Comment: Thanks but I already used a `node-notifier`. This module works well :)

Comment: This actually solved my issues — thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Notifier The garbadge collection was the real issue! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

#npm i node-notifier#

```
const notifier = require('node-notifier');



notifier.notify({
    appID: 'myApp',
    title: ' ',
    message: 'myMesaage',
    wait: true
}, function (err, response) {
    if (response !== 'timeout'){
       console.log("Notification clicked");
    }
});
```